# how to use !Sub for array of arn in cloudformation

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have function defined like this:

```
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  FunctionName: !Join
    - "-"
    - - !Ref NamePrefix
      - !FindInMap [ NameMap, SEND-SES-EMAIL-FUNCTION, NAME ]
      - !Ref NamePostfix
  Description: "Lambda function to send email with CSV file through SES"
  CodeUri: source/resources/sendSESEmailFunction
  Handler: sendSESEmail.lambda_handler
  Policies:
    - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
    - Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        - Sid: SESPermissions
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - 'ses:SendEmail'
          Resource:
            - !Sub
            - 'arn:aws:ses:${AWS::Region}:${SESAccountID}:identity/${SenderEmail}'
            - SenderEmail: !Ref SenderSESEmail
              SESAccountID: !Ref SESAccountID
            - !Sub
            - 'arn:aws:ses:${AWS::Region}:${SESAccountID}:identity/${ReceiverEmail}'
            - ReceiverEmail: 'testing'
              SESAccountID: !Ref SESAccountID
```

My goal is to use !Sub on multiple ARN's under **Resource** of Lambda policy but this is throwing error like this: Syntax errors in policy. (Service:
AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
MalformedPolicyDocument

Comment: An error?  Include exact error.

Comment: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [SenderEmail, ReceiverEmail] in the Resources block of the template
@erik258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your policy, `Resource` takes a list of resource ARNs which you're creating with Fn::Sub. But SenderEmail and ReceiverEmail are defined as separate items in the list of `Resource` not within the `!Sub` to which they apply.

[The correct structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) would be:

```
              Resource:
                - !Sub 
                  - 'arn:aws:ses:${AWS::Region}:${SESAccountID}:identity/${SenderEmail}'
                  - SenderEmail: !Ref SenderSESEmail
                    SESAccountID: !Ref SESAccountID
                - !Sub
                  -'arn:aws:ses:${AWS::Region}:${SESAccountID}:identity/${ReceiverEmail}'
                  - ReceiverEmail: 'testing'
```

I've always found the `!Sub` syntax confusing.  This is the alternative which makes the structure more clear:

```
              Resource:
                - Fn::Sub: 
                  - 'arn:aws:ses:${AWS::Region}:${SESAccountID}:identity/${SenderEmail}'
                  - SenderEmail: !Ref SenderSESEmail
                    SESAccountID: !Ref SESAccountID
                - Fn::Sub:
                  -'arn:aws:ses:${AWS::Region}:${SESAccountID}:identity/${ReceiverEmail}'
                  - ReceiverEmail: 'testing'
```

Comment: Now it's throwing Syntax error in policy, I forgot to add SESAccountID in the second SUB but still not working

Comment: should include updated yaml in your question

Comment: I've updated the code block on my main post.

Comment: the arguments to `!Sub` should be _under_ `!Sub`, you still have them next to `!Sub` in the text you show

Comment: You're right ! It is working now. Many thanks